# Why are shh keys lost on reboot of AWS ec2 instance (sage maker)?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, conda, amazon-sagemaker

I have an AWS SageMaker notebook running some ML stuff for work, and I have a private github repo with some of my commonly used functions which is formatted in such a way to be pip install-able, so I set up an SSH key by doing this:

```
ssh-keygen 

-t rsa -b 4096 -C "danielwarfield1@gmail.com"
```

enter, enter, enter (default save location no password)

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rs
```

then I copy the public key into github, then I run this to install my library

```
$PWD/pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/...
```

where `$PWD` is the directory containing pip for the conda env I'm using (tensorflow2_p36 specifically, the one that AWS provides)

this works fine, until I restart the EC2, then it appears my shh key (along with all my other installs) are lost, and I have to repeat the process. I expect the modules to be lost, I know SageMaker manages the environments, but me loosing my ssh key seems peculiar, is there a place I can save my ssh key wher it wont get lost, but I can still find it when I pip install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker` location is persisted even when you switch down the notebook instance, you can try saving things here to get them persisted. Things saved elsewhere will be lost when you switch off the instance

Regarding private git integration, you can use the [SageMaker git Notebook integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-git-repo.html), which uses Secrets Manager to safely handle your credentials

You can perform steps automatically when the notebook starts with a [lifecycle configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html). This is useful for example to standardise and automatise copying of data and environment customization